# GNU/Linux alternative to Math input panel

Tags: linux, open-source, latex

For scientific writing I am used to write formulas in LaTeX typesetting them by keyboard.

A colleague showed me how this can be done way faster: He just draws the formula with a stylus in a program named "**math input panel**" and the formula will instantly get translated to LaTeX-code he then pasted.

[image: math input panel]

Unfortunately the math input panel is only available for windows. What's the **open source alternative to GNU/Linux**?

Comment: Would you settle for non open source but free for single user in Linux? And not handwritten but picked formula/math symbol from a list or a by clicking a button?

Comment: No, I definitely want it to be open source since I often read and sometimes change the code.

Comment: I also don't want a formula picker. It simply is slower compared to typing them directly in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

From [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr) it looks like [JMathNotes](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~tapia/?page_id=269) (state of the art in 2004) does what you want. The TEX.SX question also has some other recommendations.